# How to generate list of abbreviations in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, acronyms

I used the `acronym` package (`usepackage{acronym}`) to create acronyms in my thesis. In the beginning of the document, I define the acronym as, for example, `\acrodef{USA}{United States of America}`. And then later to use this abbreviation I call it as `\ac{USA}`. How do we generate a list of Abbreviations (acronyms) as a list of figures and list of tables in LaTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `acronym` package documentation:

> Acronyms can either defined from an environment specifically
>   introduced for that purpose or by direct
>   definitions.The acronym environment allows one to define all the
>   acronyms needed by a document at a single place and is
>   self-documenting, since a table of acronyms is automatically produced.

And

> If one does not want an acronym list to be produced at all, acronyms
>   can bedefined directly thanks to the two
>   commands
>
> `\newacro{〈acronym〉}[〈short name〉]{〈full> name〉}`
>
> `\acrodef{〈acronym〉}[〈short name〉]{〈full name〉}`

Therefore, use the `acronym` environment and the `\acro` command instead of `\acrodef` if you want to have a list of `acronyms`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

Some text \ac{USA}

\section{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
 \acro{USA}{United States of America}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Compiling twice, you will get the following result:

[image]

---

For automated sorting and a lot more (formating) options, I'd recommend the `glossaries` or the `glossaries-extra` package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but why did you use `\begin{acronym}
 \acro{USA}{United States of America}
\end{acronym}`? Can't we use `acrodef` as I included in my question? yes, I have also read `glossaries` is powerful but how can we use it together with `acronym`? Because I have a huge document and all my abbreviations have been defined using `acrodef` and used with `\ac{}` command.

Comment: @Brown: As the quoted parts of the `acronym` manual show, the `\acrodef` command can be used if you don't want to have a list of abbreviations. In order to create the MWE in my answer, I just followed the example file on page 7 of the documentation where the `arconym` environment and the `\acro` command are used.

Comment: Ok thank you again. But is it common to use page numbers with acronyms?

Comment: @Brown: I don't know, but you can remove the page numbers form the list of acronyms if you remove the `withpage` option from the `acronym` package.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest the powerful `acro` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{usa}{
  short=USA,
  long=United States of America,
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
  short=EU,
  long=European Union,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ussr}{
  short=USSR,
  long=Union of Soviet Socialist Republics,
}

\begin{document}

\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}

\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}

\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I am getting an error `LaTeX3 Error: Command '\acresetall' already defined!`

Comment: @Brown You shouldn't load also `acronym`.

Comment: Super late comment, but if the acronym is 6-letters, is there a way to format

Comment: @Akriti I’m not sure what you mean.