# How to make List of Abreviation in Latex content

Tags: lists

How i can make a abreviations as List in my contents:
i use this code but i didn't get the list

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{report}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{cnn}{CNN}{Convolutional Neural Network}
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\printglossaries

\clearpage

\chapter{Foo}
when we say \Gls{cnn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492175/how-to-generate-list-of-abbreviations-in-latex

Comment: Thank you for the link .I want to do the automated sorting using glossaries