# Add a list of acronyms to a latex template

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, acronyms, acro

I tried to add a list of acronyms to the latex template below:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-oxford-mathematical-institute-phd-thesis-template/xzvzjnxbmftm

I added the following code to the file `main.tex` in the template, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492196/148579).

```
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{usa}{
  short=USA,
  long=United States of America,
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
  short=EU,
  long=European Union,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ussr}{
  short=USSR,
  long=Union of Soviet Socialist Republics,
}
```

And then I added the following code to the same `main.tex` file.

```
\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
\tableofcontents            % generate and include a table of contents
\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}
\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}
\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}
\printacronyms
\listoffigures   % generate and include a list of figures
\end{romanpages}
```

Although an **Acronym** section appears after the table of contents, the problem is that before the Acronym section and at the end of the table of contents, all acronyms are displayed as below, which is not desirable.

**United States of America (USA), USA European Union (EU), EU Union of Soviet Socialist Republics (USSR), USSR**

How to fix this problem?

See the attached screenhot.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\printacronyms` will print a list of acronyms, that is all you need. The acronyms are appearing between the table of contents and list of acronyms because you're printing them there with

```
\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}
\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}
\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}
```

As long as you use the acronyms (directly with `\ac` and friends, or just mark them as used with `\acuse`) in the body of the document then they will appear in the list.
Or to include all acronyms that are defined in the document with `\DeclareAcronym` regardless of use set `\printacronyms[display=all]`.

Comment: So how to delete the part specified in the screenshot? (I edited the uploaded image.)

Comment: Delete the `\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}
\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}
\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}` bit, you just need `\tableofcontents \printacronyms`