# Undefined control sequence error for \acro command in LaTeX

Tags: acro

I'm trying to use the \acro command to define acronyms in my LaTeX document, but I'm encountering an "Undefined control sequence" error. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Liste des abréviations}

\acro{CMS}{\emph{Content Management System}}
\medskip

\acro{baas}{\emph{Backend As A Service}}
\medskip

\acro{API}{\emph{Application Programming Interface}}
\medskip

\end{document}
```

I've included the acro package in the preamble, but I'm still getting the error. How can I fix this issue and successfully use the \acro command to define my acronyms?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The `acro` package does not offer an `\arco` command in order to define acronyms, but rather `\DeclareAcronym` with a different syntax than the one you're currently using. For an example on how to properly use the `acro` package, you may want to take a look at the following example code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492196/134144

Comment: You are probably confusing the `acro` and `acronym` packages, the former does not define a `\acro` while the latter does.  However even for `acronym`, `\acro` should be used inside an `acronym` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `acro` package you must define the acronyms in the preamble via the command `\DeclareAcronym{<ID>}{short=short text, long=long text}`.

Please read the [acro manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf) page #4 (*acro for the impatient*)

To print the full list as an unnumbered chapter use

`\printacronyms[display=all, name=Liste des abréviations]`

The example shows the use of the `\ac{<id>}` command and the like in a document.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{cms}{short= C.M.S. , long=Content Management System}
\DeclareAcronym{baas}{short= B. as S. , long=Backend As A Service}
\DeclareAcronym{api}{short=API , long=Application Programming Interface}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        first time  & \ac{cms} \\
        second time & \ac{cms} \\
        long    & \acl{cms} \\
        short   & \acs{cms} \\
        full    & \acf{cms}
    \end{tabular}
        
\printacronyms[display=all, name=Liste des abréviations] %Printing the full  list
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]